# Recently released from prison and didn't file taxes for two years. How do i file no income?

Tags: united-states, taxes

Should I file taxes with no income because of being in prison? What about the stimulus checks? Do I need to file taxes to receive it?

Comment: If you want the check _now_, you need to work with the IRS to give them your account or address. If you can wait till tax filing 2020 (which means Apr 2021), you'll get it then.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you get Social Security benefits, you will need to have filed a 2019 or 2018 tax return in order to get the check now. Yes, you can file a tax return with no income.

If you do not get the check, you can still get the tax credit when you file your 2020 tax return in 2021.